# How to use Morton Order(z order curve) in range search?

Tags: geohash

How to use Morton Order in range search?

From the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve),

In the paragraph "Use with one-dimensional data structures for range searching",
it says:

> the range being queried (x = 2, ..., 3, y = 2, ..., 6) is indicated by
>   the dotted rectangle. Its highest Z-value (MAX) is 45. In this
>   example, the value F = 19 is encountered when searching a data
>   structure in increasing Z-value direction. ......BIGMIN (36 in the
>   example).....only search in the interval between BIGMIN and MAX....

My questions are: 
1) why the **F** is 19? Why the F should not be 16?

2) How to get the **BIGMIN**?

3) Are there any web blogs demonstrate how to do the range search?